# Can $\frac{1}{\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)^{-\beta }+1}$ be arbitrarily rescaled?

Tags: functions

When $\beta > 0$, the following function has the nice feature of intersecting (0,0) from above and (1,1) from below, while nearing a step-function as $\beta$ approached infinity.

```
1/(1 + (x/(1 - x))^(-\[Beta]))
```

Can the function be generalized, or arbitrarily re-scaled, in such a way that the stated coordinates can be any ($x_{min}$, $y_{min}$) and ($x_{max}$, $y_{max}$), when  $x_{min} < x_{max}$ and $y_{min} < y_{max}$?

Answer (score 0):

\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{y_{max}-y_{min}}{\left(\frac{x-x_{min}}{x-x_{max} }\right)^{-\beta}+1} +y_{min}.
\end{eqnarray*}